# Map production checklist for organisation

Tags: cartography, workflow

I would like to create a map production workflow list for my GIS colleagues at a local public authority. When someone orders a map, I would like to have a kind of check list where we can just run through the standard questions and write them into an excel table. This would help us keep a record of what maps we have acually made, which datasets were used, who does the mapping, and a production history which is good for time management purposes.
I was thinking around the lines of creating a mask in an excel table including "Purpose","target Audience", "Output medium", "size", "Scale/resolution requirements", "Title", "north arrow"..etc...

Has anyone created something similar? Does this seem useful? Does anyone have similar documents which I could look at and compare?

Comment: Is the purpose to make sure each map has all elements necessary (you mention north arrow, title etc) or keep track of which maps have been produced and with which data (don't forget the *when*, so you know how relevant the information is)? This seems like two distinct tasks, and maybe they should result in two separate checklists?

Comment: It should be used to firstly document which mapping tasks needs to be done..ie someone calls and says" we need a map to show locations of firestations, hospitals and transport network" - Then we write down who called, details of the map,  deadlines and other user requirements etc...but also use the checklist to document whether we have included all map elements that were requested.

Comment: I don´t really want to build a relational database for such a  list...just simply an excel table which can also be printed at left on the desk as well.

Comment: For the map elements things, wouldn't it be easier to create a number of templates (for different purposes/print sizes) which already includes "everything" needed? This is not very complicated (at least in theory) in Arcmap.

Comment: We use a internal wiki to documentation the templates/locations. It takes time to setup and populate but is a quick and easy source for all employees to access and check when the map or data was last updated.

Comment: @Mapperz - any chance of a screenshot?

Comment: @RobertBuckley it is based on http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki

Answer (score 2):

Here are some resources from the [Esri Map Center](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/):

- [Map Evaluation Guidelines](http://downloads.esri.com/MappingCenter2007/arcGISResources/more/MapEvaluationGuidelines.pdf) (also see the associated [blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/05/03/using-a-mapmaking-checklist-for-map-design/) entry)
- [Making a Meaningful Map](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0911/files/mapchecklist.pdf)